Am I overlooking the solution to "Module 'fs' has been externalized for browser compatibility"?
Just so you get an understanding of the situation, I am trying to build a web game library that runs on my computer. It is pretty much a rip off of the Nintendo Wii and 3DS. I'm using Vite as the server I use to access the webpages, and WS so I can run multiplayer games and services. The next thing I want to do is file manipulation so I can create save files for whatever game, but I have been having issues with file manipulation.
I have a test run file that is suppose to change the text of "hello.txt" from "Hello there" to "Good Bye". I am using Node/fs to edit files, and when I import fs after I run index.js, I get this error:
Uncaught Error: Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "fs.fs" in client code.
I looked all over the internet to find the solution to this problem, and I have found it, but I still get this error.
For clarification, the answer was to install vite-plugin-node-polyfills and type this into vite.config.ts:
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    nodePolyfills(),
  ],
})

Is there more to this solution that I am missing, or am I doing it all wrong? Also what does, "Cannot access 'fs.fs' in client code," mean? Is this something I'm completely overlooking?
If you need anymore information, I'll be here.

Vite is a development server. It's purely for client (=browser) projects. There's no code that runs server-side in that setup. You can't use it for the purpose you're trying to use it for. You'll have to make an actual Node server outside Vite or use a different system like Next.js that's designed for this kind of thing (i.e. it's also capable of running server-side code.)

So Next.js a server like Vite, but built more for File Manipulation (among other things)?

No, Next.js is a framework for SSR applications (server-side rendering) which is what you need based on the description. Vite is not a server. If you're already far into building the app then having a separate Node server as the backend might be easier so that you don't need to rewrite the entire project.

I just might do that! Thanks for the help. I'll look into Next.js right now. :)

Something that does confuse me is the fact that I installed a plugin for vite so it will do file manipulation. How come it still isn't working even after what I did?

If you mean the node-polyfills plugin mentioned in the question then you're just mistaken about what it does. Again, Vite is a development server for browser apps. No plugin can make it handle files because it's not a server and not part of the app that you're building.

Ohhh! Now I understand. Okay, then I'll definitely look into something else. Thanks for the feed back.

Now that I have more understanding and context on programming, Module "fs" has been externalized for browser compatibility means that fs is NOT compatible client-side (the users browser).
